# ClientContext and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

If this is for Client so the Client does not need to have SharePoint installed on its computer to get it work? am I right?

I need some information to understand it, the code executed on client side so why he needs to have Sharepoint?

Answer (score 3):

Client Object Model in SharePoint has basically 3 applications, nore requiring SP installed, but for which one you need certain libraries available during development:
1. ECMA Client OM - to be used by Javascript - no SharePoint whatsoever but you need the libraries (SP.js, etc.)
2. Managed - For use from Windows Forms, Console Applications, etc. - in this one you need the Managed SharePoint assemblies
3. Silverlight Client OM - Same as #2 but you need to also link to some Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime

For more read here http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-complete-details-about.html

Hope this helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks, 
I have downloaded libraries that I needed, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime
so as you said I dont need to have SharePoint installed, 
but when I run my code Context is null

Comment: Actually you need to "connect" to the SharePoint site collection prior to using the client context. We normally use the initParams to pass parameters to either your web part/component. See this link from http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-12-ClientContextCurrent_is_null_in_Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When using the Silverlight Client Object Model you have two way of getting a valid ClientContext.

Either you specify the url of the SharePoint site to work with in the constructor to a ClientContext like this:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint");
```

Or the `<object>` tag used to load your SilverLight application should contain a `<param>` tag with name "initParams" and a value `MS.SP.url` = url. So you could use something like:

```
<param name="initParams" value="MS.SP.url=<%= Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.Url) %>" />
```

to specify it. The OOTB Silverlight web part does this. Then you can use ClientContext.Current.